# Conditional row coloring based on cell content in datatables

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I am trying to highlight rows whose content has changed upon edit.

On clicking a `+` sign on a `datatable()` initialized table rows expand to show another table that contains the history of edits of the initial row. Graphically represented this looks like:

```
   id  name  age  address
+  1   Amy   25   NY
+  2   Anne  30   TX
-  3   John  28   CA
       Jhn   28   HU
       Jon   28   AB
+  4   Max   24   AD
```

Row `id` `3` has been expanded to show its edit history . So for this particular record the `name` and `address` rows should be colored differently(should differ from the coloring of the other history row viz: `age` as age remains 28 throughout the 2 edits) as to highlight the changes.

Am at a loss as how to compare the contents of the cells of the edited rows  and highlight them using `datatables()` or otherwise.

Help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you put your current code in JSFiddle ?

Comment: please share what you have tried so far (in code)